# Custom Nav Walker sub-menu HTML construct

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu, walker

I've got my Custom Nav Walker set up and it works fine with the main menu items, and displays them how I want.

However the same HTML is being applied to the `sub-menu` elements which isn't what I want.

I'm aiming to get the `sub-menu` to have the following styling:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2 class="dropdown-text">Blog 1</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2 class="dropdown-text">Blog 2</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2 class="dropdown-text">Blog 3</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2 class="dropdown-text">Blog 4</h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the HTML Structure for the full navigation

```
<div class="postit-surround">
<a href="#">
    <div class="postit">
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/drawing-pin.png">
        </div>
        <div class="postit-title">
            <h1 class="nav-title-text">Products</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="corner-peel">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/corner-flick-cyan.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<div class="navigation-dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h2 class="dropdown-text">Products 1</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2 class="dropdown-text">Products 2</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2 class="dropdown-text">Products 3</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2 class="dropdown-text">Products 4</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2 class="dropdown-text">Products 5</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML call for the wp_nav_menu:

```
<div class="navigation-container">
<?php 

$walker = new my_nav_walker;
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'menu' => 'ul', 'menu_class' => 'navigation', 'menu_id' => '', 'walker' => $walker ) ); 


?>
</div>
```

Here is the construct for my Custom Walker HTML: (NOTE: I'm really new to this, so this is going to be messy...)

```
class my_nav_walker extends Walker {
       function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

            $direct = get_template_directory_uri();

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<div class="postit-surround">';
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */

            $item_output .= '<div class="postit">
                                    <div class="pin">';
            $item_output .= '<img src="' . $direct . '/assets/drawing-pin.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="postit-title">
                                            <h1 class="nav-title-text">';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;

            $item_output .= '</h1>
                            </div>
                                    <div class="corner-peel">
                                            <img src="' . $direct . '/assets/corner-flick-green.png">
                                    </div>
                            </div>';
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= '</div>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

        }    

} // Walker_Nav_Menu
```

Here's the CSS if needed:

[PasteBin Link](http://pastebin.com/ZwCChaR3)

I'm not sure if I'm doing the construct right to get the separate styling that I want.

What would you advise?

Are there any alternatives?

Constructive Criticism on the code? (Don't be too harsh! :P)

EDIT -----:

I've done some more research into understanding the php code, and I now realise where the defining of the start and end of the sub-menu starts (With start_lvl and end_lvl), but I still don't understand how to separate what code goes to the Parent navigation panes, and which goes to their respective sub-menus.

**This is what I'm after with the display of the naviagtion: http://jsfiddle.net/TPD5L/**

Comment: "Constructive Criticism on the code?". Well stated. ;)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks :) Even I cringe at the code, god knows what most people seeing it are thinking!

Comment: which method are you overridding? and i don't think you need to have a custom walker, you can get it done using wp_nav_menu function with proper arguments, plz post the full code including the method names of your custom walker

Comment: @MortalViews Question Edited to include FULL Custom Walker Code, and HTML wp_nav_menu call.

Comment: Hi, when you are extending the parent class, you don't need to include any method that you are not overriding. check: the general example http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

Comment: @MortalViews Could you elaborate? I don't understand a lot of this :)

Comment: check out the General Menu Example @   http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker and also http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Thanks for that, but I don't understand how that allows me to separate the HTML for the top-level items and the sub-menu.

Comment: how is your menu structure? is it? <ul><li><a>Services</a><ul clas='submenu'><li><a>Wolf Hunting</a></li><li><a>Horse Hunting</a></li></ul></li></ul> ie: MainMenu item->sub menu items

Comment: I'll add it to the question

Comment: @MortalViews Added.

Comment: Please take a look at the original Walker and remove all of the methods from your walker that are the same as the original. When you `extend` you have a kind of parent/child relationship. You don't have to duplicate methods that exist in the parent unless you want to change them. Once you do that I'll take another look. There is too much unnecessary code as is.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Is that better? I just removed everything that wasn't needed for the HTML structure generation.

Comment: Better, but you've removed too much. You must still have the method definitions for the methods you are using-- the `function start_el(...)` part.

Comment: @s_ha_dum There we go, should be good now. Although, when I have this on my localhost site, I'm getting: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/L2PK2zGN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Copy paste the below code into your function. 
and then in template use

```
my_nav_menu($menu_location);
```

**//put this in your functions**

```
class MY_Menu_Walker_Ext extends Walker {

    var $tree_type = array('post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom');
    var $db_fields = array('parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id');

    function start_el(&$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0) {
        $output .="<li><h2 class='dropdown-text'>{$object->title}</h2>";
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $output.='</li>';
    }

}

class my_custom_menu {

    public $menu;
    public $menuItems;
    public $parents;
    public $walker;

    public function __construct($menu_location) {
        $this->setMenu($menu_location);
        $this->getMenuItems();
        $this->getParents();

        $this->walker = new MY_Menu_Walker_Ext();
    }

    public function drawMenu() {

    }

    public function setMenu($menu_location) {

        $this->menu = $this->getMenuByLocation($menu_location);
    }

    protected function getMenuByLocation($menu_location) {
        $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

        $menu = null;
        if ($locations && isset($locations[$menu_location])) {
            $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_location]);
        }

        return $menu;
    }

    public function get() {

    }

    public function getMenuItems() {
        if ($this->menuItems)
            return $this->menuItems;
        $this->menuItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($this->menu);

        return $this->menuItems;
    }

    public function getParents() {
        if ($this->parents)
            return $this->parents;
        $parents = array();

        foreach ($this->menuItems as $item) {
            if ($item->menu_item_parent == 0) {
                array_push($parents, $item);
            }
        }

        $this->parents = $parents;
        return $this->parents;
    }

    public function getChild($parent_id) {

        $childs = array();


        foreach ($this->menuItems as $item) {
            if ($parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent) {
                $item->menu_item_parent = 0;

                array_push($childs, $item);
                foreach ($this->menuItems as $item1) {
                    if ($item->ID == $item1->menu_item_parent) {
                        array_push($childs, $item1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        return $childs;
    }

    public function draw() {
        echo "<div class='postit-surround'>";

        foreach ($this->parents as $item) {
            $this->displayParentHTML($item->title);
            $this->drawChildren($this->getChild($item->ID));
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }

    public function displayParentHTML($title) {
        ?>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="postit">
                <div class="pin">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/drawing-pin.png">
                </div>
                <div class="postit-title">
                    <h1 class="nav-title-text"><?php echo $title ?></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="corner-peel">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/corner-flick-cyan.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>


        <?php
    }

    public function drawChildren($children) {
        $defaults = array('menu' => '', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => '', 'container_id' => '', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => '',
            'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            'depth' => 0, 'walker' => '', 'theme_location' => '');
        $args = array(
            'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
            'container' => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'navigation-dropdown',
            'items_wrap' => '<ul >%3$s</ul>',
            'depth' => 0,
        );
        $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);

        echo "<div class='navigation-dropdown'><ul>";
        echo $this->walker->walk($children, 2, $args);
        echo "</ul></div>";
    }

}

function my_nav_menu($name = null) {
    $myMenu = new my_custom_menu($name);
    $myMenu->draw();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine on it's own, however i'm struggling to see how to integrate that with my top-level Walker to get the overall structure stated in the question?

Comment: i didn't get you. you don't need another top-level Walker.

Comment: replace your my_nav_walker class with this one. and in the template where you want to display the nave menu. copy paste the code in the second section. note: the output will include the container div also

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding what I'm after with the navigation (I've been really unclear in my question, sorry for that) See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TPD5L/

Comment: okay, the html for the 'postit' part should be includeed in the template. <post it div>< the post it code></> Here call the nav menu </div>

Comment: you should NOT try to get the whole html from the wp_nav_menu. use wp_nav_menu just for the 'menu' part. rest should be included in the template code, you getting me?

Comment: So rather than using the wp_nav_menu to get the top-level menu items, just use it to get the children elements?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14599/discussion-between-mortalviews-and-mallander)